# Store text file into array in javascript in complete code

Tags: javascript, html

I have text file like this :

```
'Ontario', 51.567841, -86.902662 'North Dacota',48.112188, -100.152173 'South Dacota',45.741832, -99.251294 'Montana',47.950558, -106.875805
```

I need to store it into an array in JavaScript in complete code like this:

```
var locations = [
      ['Ontario', 51.567841, -86.902662],
      ['North Dacota',48.112188, -100.152173],
      ['South Dacota',45.741832, -99.251294],
      ['Montana',47.950558, -106.875805]

    ];
```

Comment: Use the PHP explode function and set a comma as the delimiter

http://php.net/explode

Comment: @detheridge02 this is a javascript question. OP, what did you try so far?

Comment: So it is!

In that case read the text file line by line within a loop and then...

locations.push = csvLine.split(',');

Comment: I don't see a comma after every name and number. If its a typo then you can first copy the content of the text file on to a string and then use yourTxtFileString.split(",");

Comment: As we see, you've already done what you wanted. Why do you ask this question then?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```js
var str = "'Ontario', 51.567841, -86.902662 'North Dacota',48.112188, -100.152173 'South Dacota',45.741832, -99.251294 'Montana',47.950558, -106.875805";

var formattedArray = str.replace(/,\s?/g, ',').replace(/\s(')\b|\b(')\s/g, '***').split('***');

var result = formattedArray.map(function (value) {

  return value.replace(/'/g, '').split(',');
  
});

alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```